# The multiplicative order of 2 modulo p prime congruent to 1(mod 8)

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\mathrm{ord}_p(2)$ be the order of 2 in the multiplicative group modulo $p$. Define the set $C_2:=\{p\equiv1\pmod{8}\ {\rm{prime}}\mid \mathrm{ord}_p(2)\equiv 2\pmod{4}\}=\{281,617,1033,1049,1097,1193,1481,1553,1753,1777,...\}$.

Question: Is $C_2$ infinite or finite?

Comment: When $p\equiv9\pmod{16}$, this is equivalent to $2$ being a $4$th power but not an $8$th power modulo $p$, which is equvialent to the polynomial $x^8-2$ factoring into the product of four irreducible quadratics modulo $p$. Can the set of such primes be proved infinite with the Chebotarev density theorem?

Comment: Also, I do not understand how p congruent to 9 (mod 16) implies 2 being a 4th power (mod p). Here is a counter-example: Let p=41. Then 2 is square of 17 (mod 41), but 17 is a primitive root (mod 41). Hence 2 can not be a 4th power (mod 41).

Comment: I mean to say that ord$_p(2) \equiv 2\pmod 4$ is equivalent to $2$ being a $4$th power but not an $8$th power modulo $p$. In your example, ord$_{41}(2) = 20 \not\equiv 2\pmod 4$.

Comment: Density of $C_2$ can be indeed calculated by Chebotarev density theorem, and equals $1/24$. Not really a research level question though.

Comment: @Jarek Kuben Could you, please, explain how you calculated the density of $C_2$?

Comment: Well, not in a comment, and the question was closed. [This](https://eudml.org/doc/161442) paper by Hasse (in German) contains a proof that the set of odd primes such that $2\mid\mathrm{ord}_p(2)$ has density $17/24$. The same method can be applied here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Same thanks to G. Martin. He is right, claiming that infinitude of those $p\in C_2$, which are $9\pmod{16}$, implies infinitude of $C_2$.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to bet, I'd say yes. It looks like it might happen about $\frac{1}{6}$ of the time.

Up to $40,000$ there are $1026$ primes $p=8k+1$ which are $1 \bmod 8.$ It would appear likely that the probabilities of the order of $2$ $\bmod p$ being, $0 \bmod 4,$ $ 2 \bmod 4,$ and $1 \bmod 2$ settle to stable values of *roughly* $\frac23,\frac16,\frac16$ respectively.

here is a graph showing the evolving percentages over these $1026$ primes. The final counts are $699,176$ and $151$ for $0,2 \bmod 4$ and $1 \bmod 2.$

[image]

Suppose that $p-1=2^em$ with $m$ odd and $e \geq 3.$  We know that $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ so its order is some divisor of $2^{e-1}m.$ Say $2^fj$ for some (odd) divisor $j$ of $m$ and $f \lt e.$ Given this information, one might naively expect it to be $j,2j,4j,\cdots$ with probabilities in ratio $1:1:2:4:\cdots.$ That is too naive but it does seem to be the case that the larger $e$ is, the more likely that the order of $2$ is at least a multiple of $4.$